# Using a widget to add cart shortcode in WooCommerce Archive product pages

Tags: woocommerce, product, cart

I created widget to add `[woocommerce_cart]` to my archive product sidebar

Number of product per row is set to 3.

After submit add to cart the number of product per row change to 2 !

Any guidance on that?

Here is [my archive product link](http://ewebs.ir/sanseven/product-category/%D9%BE%DB%8C%D8%AA%D8%B2%D8%A7/):

Here is the widget code:

```
// Creating the widget basket
class wpb_widget extends WP_Widget {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
            // Base ID of your widget
            'wpb_widget',

            // Widget name will appear in UI
            __('ابزارک سبد خرید', 'wpb_widget_domain'),
            // Widget description
            array( 'description' => __( 'سبد خرید اختصاصی ', 'wpb_widget_domain' ), )
        );
    }

    // Creating widget front-end
    // This is where the action happens
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );
        // before widget arguments are defined by themes
        echo $args['before_widget'];
        // This is where you run the code and display the output
?>
    <div class="header__card-icon" >
        <a href="<?php echo wc_get_cart_url(); ?>"title="<?php is_rtl() ? _e( 'نمایش سبد خرید' ) : _e( 'View your shopping cart' );  ?>">
            <span class="demo-icon icon-basket-1"> &#xe832; </span>
            <?php // if ( ! empty( $title ) ) echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title']; ?>
        </a>
        <a class="cart-contents"  id="mini-cart-count" href="<?php echo wc_get_cart_url(); ?>" title="<?php is_rtl() ? _e( 'نمایش سبد خرید' ) : _e( 'View your shopping cart');  ?>" ><?php if(WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count()>0){ echo sprintf( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() );} ?> </a>
    </div>
    <!--header__card-icon-->
    <h3 class="widget-title"> ســبــد خــریــد </h3>
    <?php
        echo do_shortcode('[woocommerce_cart]');
        // after widget arguments are defined by themes
        echo $args['after_widget'];
    }


    // Widget Backend
    public function form( $instance ) {
        if ( isset( $instance[ 'title' ] ) ) {
            $title = $instance[ 'title' ];
        }
        else {
            $title = __( '', 'wpb_widget_domain' );
        }
        // Widget admin form
?>
    <p>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label>
    <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" />
    </p>
    <?php
    }

    // Updating widget replacing old instances with new
    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = array();
        $instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';
        return $instance;
    }
} // Class wpb_widget ends here

// Register and load the widget
function wpb_load_widget() {
    register_widget( 'wpb_widget' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wpb_load_widget' );
```